# Reference counted smart pointer that deletes owned object with ref count greater than zero?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have a design where objects are simultaneously owned by 2 queues. Occasionally the queues themselves may be deleted. In this case, all objects in the queue must be deleted and removed from the other queue they are in.

The current solution has the owned objects knowing about the two owning queues, but this introduces ugly coupling.

Is there a smart pointer class that could help me? Construction would be either with a 'new' or a copy of an existing pointer. Destruction would delete the owned resource. Access would be like a weak_ptr, giving the possibility of pointing to null.

I guess it might need a specific 'destroy' method, to make sure that temporary copies of pointers didn't free the resource.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Thanks, 
Tony

Answer (score 1):

You want deletion of a queued object to remove it from the other queue, without coupling it to the queue.

One approach that would avoid this coupling would be to *mark* the object as removed, without actually removing it.

- Use wrapper objects as the members of the queues. A logically queued object has two wrapper objects, one for each queue.
- Each wrapper contains a boost::shared_ptr to the object logically a member of each queue.
- The wrapper's destructor *marks* the logically queued object as dead.
- When pulling items off the queue, ignore the ones marked dead.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds good, but in the event that one queue dies and we have 'hanging' wrappers (and still actual queued objects) in the other queue, when do they get deleted? I guess instead of ignoring marked dead items, we must delete them.

Comment: Probem here would be if one queue went quiet but wasn't deleted. Perhaps the queues could search for dead objects periodically themselves.

Comment: Are you periodically pulling items out of each queue? If so, the answer to the "when" question above is "when they're removed from the other queue." In the second comment, what does "go quiet" mean?

Comment: Sorry for the very imprecise language. By 'go quiet' I meant that the queue's client stopped pulling items off the queue. As you can see, if that can happen it causes a problem for using queue access to delete the logically dead objects, but the queues could do the garbage collection without being popped.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, having the queues dispose of dead objects themselves. Is queue overflow a concern for you as well, if the consumers stop pulling items?

Comment: Overflow should not be a problem. 1) throughput is low. 2) a consumer which stops pulling items will announce systemwide that it is disfunctional, which will stop pushes to the queue. Or it should... hmmm perhaps I should think about that a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there aren't any reusable solutions to reference counting in the presence of reference cycles.  There are solutions, but they are either specific to the pattern of reference cycles that's allowed, or garbage collectors.  From the way you described the problem, you need to be able to figure out both what objects a given queue owns (so you can delete the queue) and what queues own a given object (so you can remove an object from all queues).  So you have reference cycles.

To fix the ugly coupling problem,  I would suggest having queues contain proxy objects, each of which owns the real object and knows what queues own it.  The queue methods would use and update these proxy objects.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I googled 'reference cycles'. I'm not convinced the cycle is a problem here, although I see why they affect the general case, and therefore why there is no general solution. Andy's answer looks a bit like a garbage collector, maybe that is the way to go.